# Search on worklist does not work in SAPUI5 Fiori Template Application

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

Hi SAPUI5 developers,

I made a Firori Worklist project inside of WebIDE. I connected it to an OData server and selected SAPUI version 1.38 as default.

It shows the worklist correctly and I can press on items and move between views and visit the object especially.

So everything seems to work fine.

The only thing that is not working is the search box. Its event is triggered whenever I type something inside it and press enter, but it does not filter anything.

The functions that are called are as follow:

```
onSearch: function(oEvent) {

        if (oEvent.getParameters().refreshButtonPressed) {
            // Search field's 'refresh' button has been pressed.
            // This is visible if you select any master list item.
            // In this case no new search is triggered, we only
            // refresh the list binding.
            this.onRefresh();
        } else { 
            var oTableSearchState = [];
            var sQuery = oEvent.getParameter("query");

            if (sQuery && sQuery.length > 0) {
                oTableSearchState = [new Filter("ZBrandName", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery)];
            } 
            this._applySearch(oTableSearchState);
        }

    },
     /**
     * Internal helper method to apply both filter and search state together on the list binding
     * @param {object} oTableSearchState an array of filters for the search
     * @private
     */
    _applySearch: function(oTableSearchState) {
        var oTable = this.byId("table"),
            oViewModel = this.getModel("worklistView");
            console.log(oTable);
        oTable.getBinding("items").filter(oTableSearchState, "Application");
        // changes the noDataText of the list in case there are no filter results
        if (oTableSearchState.length !== 0) {
            oViewModel.setProperty("/tableNoDataText", this.getResourceBundle().getText("worklistNoDataWithSearchText"));
        }
    },
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any errors in console? sQuery has value?
`oTable.getBinding("items").filter(oTableSearchState, "Application");` could be culprit

Comment: No errors inside of the console. And I didn't made any changes inside of the original code that is made by the Web IDE. Yes sQuery has value and all other objects as well.

Comment: does your odata has property called `ZBrandName`. Can you put sample Odata here?

Comment: and try `oTable.getBinding("rows").filter(oTableSearchState, "Application");`

Comment: Yes My OData has the field `ZBrandName`. As I said it shows this item in the table correctly. Also I tested your suggested correction but it does not work.

Comment: @SunilBN For `rows` it throws error. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126304/discussion-between-sunil-b-n-and-mahdi-jaberzadeh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that I reported may happen for others also thus I replied to my question because I found the answer.

The story is that when I used NorthWind OData service the Fiori Worklist template of the SAP WebIDE works fine and I could see a list of items and search on them (filter).

But when I used our internal SAP ERP OData Service I could see the list of items but I couldn't filter them.

Thus I thought the problem is related to SAP and it can not update the view.

But in fact, SAPUI5 sends a new request to OData Server for each filtering, while I thought the filtering is something that is done inside of the browser.

Therefore, the problem was related to our OData Service implementation that ignored the request options. While we had to implement whole the functionality of the OData specifications in our OData service.

I hope this info works for other who encounter this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter(oTableSearchState, true);
oTable.getBinding("items").filter(oFilter, "Application");
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Can you create a Fiori App with Northwind Odata? I have same problem with that also.

Comment: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.Filtering/code/Controller.controller.js
Things are working here

Comment: It works with OData services like as NorthWind but my OData service is placed onPremise server and it seems the WebIDE have problem related to setting parameters correctly for Premise services.